# How to let threads continues cycle

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, cycle, continue

I made a simple script in python 3 that enters in some folders (all called "recup_dir.x", x stays for a number from 1 to 777) and searches for files containing "firefox" word. Since the files are so much and the process will take much long, I decided to implement multithreading. Here is the code:

```
import os, threading

def loop():
    for x in range(800):
        inizialize().start()

class inizialize(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        self.program()

    def program(self):
        n = list(range(778))
        n.pop(0)
        for z in n:
            Path = ("/home/user/Desktop/files/recup_dir.%s/" % (z))
            filelist = os.listdir(Path)
            print (Path)
            for x in filelist:
                try:
                    with open(Path + x, "r", encoding="ascii") as y:
                        for line in y:
                            if "firefox" in line:
                                print ("Found in %s !" % (x))
                                exit (1)
                except:
                    pass

loop()
```

The problem is that threads (that are 800) always do the same operations and they never pass to the next folder. They always stay on the first one (recup_dir.1).

How can I do to let threads continue searching in the other folders?

Answer (score 1):

You don't distribute the work among your threads.
Try passing each thread which task it should do

Here is your example - changed:

```
import os, threading

def loop():
    for x in range(800):
        inizialize(x).start()

class inizialize(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, x):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.x = x

    def run(self):
        self.program()

    def program(self):

        z = self.x #each thread starts with a different number
        path = ("cheese.%s/" % (z))
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            return 
        filelist = os.listdir(path)
        print (path)
        for x in filelist:
            try:
                with open(path + x, "r", encoding="ascii") as y:
                    for line in y:
                        if "firefox" in line:
                            print ("Found in %s !" % (x))
                            exit (1)
            except:
                pass

loop()
```

Comment: it works! but please, since I am a newbie, could you please add more comments so I can better understand the code you posted? i'd really appreciate it.. for example I didn't get what's the usage of the first funcion (__init__)

Comment: no, it doens't work... the system says "Found in blabla" but if I check in that file, there's not the keyword.

Comment: try printing the line and line number to debug your problem